# Text box input in FormObject

Tags: input-forms

I want to make (and then cloud deploy) a form that allows users to type a paragraph. The default input for a string is a single line. I read in a post somewhere on stack exchange that using "Text" will produce a multi-line input box, but on my system (MacOS, MMA 13.2) it instead produces a "Browse" button to upload a file. For example:

```
FormObject[{"first" -> "String", "second" -> "Text"}]
```

yields the following:

[image: example]

I can't seem to find anywhere in the documentation for forms (or indeed any kind of user input) how to obtain a larger box for entering text.